# Does this asymptotic inequality on certain sequences always hold with these constraints?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a_n$, $b_n$ be positive real sequences. Suppose they are increasing, divergent to $+\infty$ and satisfy $$a_n-b_n\in O\left(\frac{b_n}{\log^2 b_n}\right)\tag{1},$$ $$b_{n+1}-b_n\in o(b_n^r) \ \text{for some $r<1$}, \tag{2}$$and $$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1.\tag{3}$$Then do we have $$\left(\dfrac{\log a_{n}}{\log a_{n+1}}-\dfrac1{b_{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\dfrac1{b_{n}-1}\right)>\left(1-\frac2{b_{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{\log a_{n}}{b_{n}\log a_{n-1}}\right) \tag{$\star$}$$ for all large enough $n$?

I think I have proved a slightly less general form of this problem, in fact moving all the factors of $(\star)$ to the same side and proving monotonicity. I do think the general case holds, and should be provable like that. Is it? Is a more elegant approach possible?

Comment: When you say "divergent", do you mean diverges to $+\infty$? RIght now the sequences could be $a_n=\frac32+\cos n$ for example (which also causes problems with the signs of their logarithms). Also we can't expect $(\star)$ for every $n$, but only sufficiently large $n$, right? Note that your hypotheses on $a_n$ and $b_n$ imply that $\frac{\log a_n}{\log a_{n+1}}$ tends to $1$ as $a_n\to\infty$, which is probably all you need to prove that $(\star)$ eventually holds when $b_n\to\infty$.

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, all of your remarks are correct. For the divergence part, I was taught to use the word "irregular" when the limit doesn't exist even in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$; is it not common? And yes, I forgot about writing "for all large enough $n$", let me fix this. Regarding $(\star)$, is it so simple? That is, I would expect $(1)$ to be necessary.

Comment: * I would expect $(1)$, or at least a small refinement of it, to be necessary

Comment: Aha, it isn't as I expected: the answer is no, as I'll describe below. The problem is that the $(\log a_n)/\log a_{n+1}$ can be significantly less than $1$, much more so than $1-1/b_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, set $b_n=n$ and $a_n=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor^2$ for all $n$. Then indeed $a_n-b_n=O(\sqrt{b_n})$ and $b_{n+1}-b_n=O(1)$. However, if $n+1=k^2$ is a perfect square, then $a_{n+1}=k^2$ while $a_n=a_{n-1}=(k-1)^2$. Writing everything in terms of $k$, we have
\begin{align*}
\bigg(\frac{\log a_{n}}{\log a_{n+1}}-\frac1{b_{n+1}}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac1{b_{n}-1}\bigg) &= \bigg(\frac{2 \log (k-1)}{2 \log k}-\frac1{k^2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac1{k^2-2}\bigg) \\
&= \bigg(\frac{\log k + \log (1-1/k)}{\log k}-\frac1{k^2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac1{k^2-2}\bigg) \\
&= \bigg(\frac{\log k - 1/k + O(1/k^2))}{\log k}+O(1/k^2)\bigg)\bigg(1+O(1/k^2)\bigg) \\
&= 1 - \frac1{k\log k} + O(1/k^2),
\end{align*}
while
\begin{align*}
\bigg(1-\frac2{b_{n+1}}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{\log a_{n}}{b_{n}\log a_{n-1}}\bigg) &= \bigg(1-\frac2{k^2+1}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{2\log (k-1)}{2(k^2-1)\log (k-1)}\bigg) \\
&= 1 + O(1/k^2),
\end{align*}
and so the inequality $(\star)$ fails when $k$ is large enough.

Comment: +1, thank you. Woult it be easy to state what else $a_n$ and $b_n$ need to satisfy in order to have $(\star)$?

Comment: Say, what if we take $a_{n+1}-a_n=\log b_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}-b_n\ge2$?

Comment: My hope is that a study of this one provided example will help you understand the general issues well enough to judge further variants for yourself.

Comment: Fair enough, I will. :)